# MVC3 Lookup list html helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Apologies if this is something that I'm missing something simple on, but here it is anyway.  I'm happy to pointed in the direction of articles etc. if that's easier.

Is there a helper that will display a value from a list given an ID.

What I'm looking for is to be able to do something like the following in Razor:

```
@Html.LookedUpValueFor(model => model.id, Lists.SelectList1)
```

In the example above, I'd expect Lists.SelectList1 to be a static SelectList where there is an "id" in the SelectList's "Value" column.

The Goal is to make it so that the "Name" is displayed instead of the "ID".  I could do this manually I'm sure, but I'm thinking that MVC should have some way to acheive my goal easily.

Ideally I would have liked to have attributed the member in the ViewModel I created to say that it's "LookupList" is a particular thing.

```
[LookupList(Lists.SelectList1, "id")]
```

or even better

```
[LookupList(Lists.StandardList, "id")]
```

where "id" is a member on the classes that form the list.

If there isn't, is there some other recommended way to acheive this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I take it you just want to show the name and not a drop down list?

If this is the case, then you should probably use a custom DisplayTemplate, so you'd call:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.id, "LookupList")
```

Where 'LookupList' is the name of display template defined in a sub folder called DisplayTemplates (an MVC naming convention).

This display template would look something like:

```
@model int
@using System.Linq

@Lists.SelectList1.Single(s => s.Value == Model.ToString()).Text
```

Your view shouldn't have this logic though so this should probably be in a separate html helper as you suggest

Comment: That did it, but in case others don't know... DisplayTemplates needs to go in "Views\Shared" or "Views\<controllerName>".  Quite a neat and reusable solution.  Even allows [UIHint("LookupList")] as a decorated... ticks all the boxes!